# Как спроектировать схему базы данных (сотрудники, оборудование, документация)?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, er-diagram

У каждого сотрудника есть прикрепленное к нему оборудование, у каждого оборудования есть свой список прикрепленных документов, закрепленное оборудование располагается в определенном месте.

Как мне подсказали, необходимы промежуточные таблицы (список оборудования и список документов). Как правильно их связать?

[сама схема](https://www.dropbox.com/s/61kcbzwcxmyc7ki/db.png?dl=0)

Comment: три основные таблицы: оборудование, документы, сотрудники. а для того чтобы хранить связи можно создать: оборудование_документы, оборудование_сотрудники.

Comment: в таблице оборудование_документы будет: [oборудование.Id], [документы.id]. аналогично в другой таблице. можно еще дату добавить - чтобы было понятно, когда была создана связь.

Comment: [вот так](https://www.dropbox.com/s/95mw2d8vj5jyon6/db2.png?dl=0) будет правильно?

Comment: т.е. при такой схеме на каждого сотрудника можно повесить несколько видов  оборудования и каждое оборудование может иметь несколько документов?

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев от [Stack](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/196972/stack)*

Три основные таблицы:

- оборудование,
- документы,
- сотрудники.

Для того чтобы хранить связи можно создать две промежуточные таблицы:

- оборудование_документы,
- оборудование_сотрудники.

В таблице оборудование_документы будут следующие внешние ключи: [oборудование.Id], [документы.id]. Аналогично в таблице оборудование_сотрудники будут следующие внешние ключи: [oборудование.Id], [сотрудники.id]. Можно еще дату добавить - чтобы было понятно, когда была создана связь.